# Game Logic - Football - How to maintain goalkeeper catch rate

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

My goalkeeper should maintain a 80% catch rate at all times in a Football Game.

There can be unlimited attempts at scoring by players.

Goalkeeper has to prevent 80% of the kicks from reaching.
How can I maintain this rate when i do not know how many kicks are going to come through.

The kicks are virtually endless. For every kick received the goalkeeper has to either catch it or leave to make sure he stays in the 80% rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: keep track of total kicks and blocks.

If blocks/kicks < 80% then block, otherwise let through.